# (python) solving for roots of equation that includes probabilistic distribution

Tags: python-3.x, math, statistics, distribution, calculus

I am quite new to this, but I need solution to mathematical problem, which involves finding roots of a function, that involves cumulative density function (several).

For simplicity I tried to code similar procedure, but with as simple function as possible but even that doesn't work.

Would anyone tell me please what am I doing wrong?

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
y=sy.Symbol('y')

def cdf(x):
 cdf_norm=norm.cdf(x,100,20)
 return cdf_norm

result=fsolve(y**2-14*y+7-cdf(y))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that fsolve requires that the first argument is a *function.* However, you passed it an *expression* which gets evaluated to some value, however, the expression has a variable name y which is undefined, so the interpreter throws a `NameError`. Also, it will require one more argument, an ndarray containing the estimates to the roots. So, one easy solution is to define another function:

```
def f(y):
    return y**2 - 14*y + 7 - cdf(y)
result = fsolve(f, np.array([1,0])
print(result)
```

I get the following result:

`array([ 0.51925928,  0.51925928])`